# How does the python interpreter know that only specific variables in the equation are to be multiplied by the number of days?

Tags: python

I am working on practice examples on edabit using python. One of the examples I am stuck on is as follows:

Create a function that takes the number of daily average recovered cases recovers, daily average new_cases, current active_cases, and returns the number of days it will take to reach zero cases.

def end_corona(recovers, new_cases, active_cases):

end_corona(4000, 2000, 77000) ➞ 39

end_corona(3000, 2000, 50699) ➞ 51

end_corona(30000, 25000, 390205) ➞ 79

Below is one of the correct solutions that I am not quite sure how the interpreter knows that only "new_cases" and "recovers" are supposed to be multiplied by the number of days (d). Somehow this solution does work but can someone explain to me why and how?

```
def end_corona(recovers, new_cases, active_cases):
   days = 0
   while active_cases > 0:
      days += 1
      active_cases = active_cases-recovers+new_cases
   return days
```

Comment: There is no actual multiplication or division going on here in the typical sense. The code is simply subtracting `recovers + new_cases` from the current amount of active cases. This is amount to something like `active_cases / math.abs(new_cases - recovers)`. So the code does not "know" to multiply them by `days`  but with the way the math works, they amount to the same thing in the same way that `5 + 5 + 5 == 5 * 3`

Comment: ok but based on the code I have written above somehow the code knows to only add and subtract the new_cases and the recovered from the original total active cases. I'm not understanding how we get the right answer based on what we are feeding into python because all we are telling the program is: active_cases = active_cases- recovers + new_cases. It doesnt know which variables should be multiplied everytime we iterate etc.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't understanding how the loop works. Suppose `recovers = 3`, `new_cases = 1` and `active_cases = 3`. The loop will iterate until `active_cases > 0`. By substituting the variables with their values in iteration 1: `active_cases = 3 - 3 + 1` therefore `active_cases = 1` and `days = 1`. On iteration 2: `active_cases = 1 - 3 + 1` therefore `active_cases = -1` and `days = 2`. Since `active_cases <= 0` the loop stops iterating and `days == 2`. Its the same as manually checking how many times 3 goes into 9. 9 - 3 = 6 - 3 = 3 - 3 = 0 therefor 3 goes into 9 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

The function is running in a loop. So in each iteration it subtracts the daily average recovered cases from the active cases and adds the daily average new cases and increase the number of days by one. It runs until the active cases are not zero and returns the total number of days it would take to get to zero cases.

Comment: ok but based on the code I have written above somehow the code knows to only add and subtract the new_cases and the recovered from the original total active cases. I'm not understanding how we get the right answer based  on what we are feeding into python because all we are telling the program is: active_cases = active_cases- recovers + new_cases. It doesnt know which variables should be multiplied everytime we iterate etc.

Comment: Okay so i think your confusion is based on the loop part. The condition "while active_cases > 0" checks whether the active cases have become zero. If they are not it runs the loop again. It keeps on iterating until the active cases are less than or equal to zero. So we don't need to multiply it with anything. It keeps on running until the condition is met.